# node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code 8

Tags: .net-core

Working on my first .net core application, a build gave me this error.
build on SPA application ends up with this Error    MSB3073 "The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code 8"

Comment: Run >node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js on the cli to see the actual error.